# Getting the IPv6 header as part of the packet

Tags: sockets, networking, ipv6

When applications use raw sockets with IPv4, they can get (and set) the IPv4 header as part of the packet using the IP_HDRINCL option.

Along similar lines, how can an application obtain the IPv6 header as part of the (IPv6) packet?  I understand that using raw sockets does not help here.

Can I use ioctl() in lieu of sockets to get what I want? Btw, I'm trying to achieve this on Linux.

Comment: IP_HDRINCL should be working equally for both IPv4 and IPv6 since the socket is providing the RAW data for your app to interpret. If that is not happening, then please provide your actual code that is creating and reading the socket.

Comment: IPv6 has a different set of options, the equivalent is `IPV6_HDRINCL` however it does not have widespread support.  This implies you may need to drop down to raw packet capture, libpcap and friends.

Comment: @Steve-o: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740506           This documentation says that the option can be used only to add an IPv6 header while sending and that the IPv6 receive packet never includes the IPv6 packet header.

Comment: @Maddy There are chances that the Microsoft behaviour is distinct from the Linux one.

Comment: @glglgl: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network.general/month=20040901/page=8 also suggests that the option is not supported on Linux.

Comment: This RFC talks about how one could access the IPv6 and extension headers: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3542. Unfortunately, it does not provide an option to access the 'payload length' field in the header, which is what I'm after.